# PHP session is not storing any data in my array

Tags: php, session

It was working, but only on chrome and only on my PC, suddenly it stopped working completely, after I closed and reopened chrome. Now it wont store any data in my session. 
http://xeon.spskladno.cz/~filipt/Fourth.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);


   $num1=$_POST["num1"];
   $num2=$_POST["num2"];
   $action=$_POST["action"];
   $memory=$_POST["memory"];



 if($action=='+')
      $vys=$num1+$num2;

  if($action=='-')
      $vys=$num1-$num2; 

  if($action=='*')
      $vys=$num1*$num2; 

  if($action=='/')
      $vys=$num1/$num2;           

  ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>

<form action="Fourth.php" method="post">



  Cislo1: <br>
    <input type="number" name="num1" value="<?php echo $num1;?>" >
          <br>
  Cislo2: <br>
    <input type="number" name="num2" value="<?php echo $num2;?>">
          <br>
  Akce:  <br>
     <select name="action" >
        <option value="+">Scitani</option>
        <option value="-">Odcitani</option>
        <option value="*">Nasobeni</option>
        <option value="/">Deleni</option>
     </select>

          <br>
  Pocet ulozenych vypoctu:<br>
      <input type="number" name="memory" value="<?php echo $memory;?>">
          <br><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Spocti">


</form> 
</body>
</html><?php

      if((strlen(trim($_POST["num1"]))==0)||(strlen(trim($_POST["num2"]))==0)||(strlen(trim($_POST["memory"]))==0))
          die("Vyplnte prosim obe cisla a pocet ulozenych vypoctu."); 

        if($action=='+'){

        echo "Vysledek prikaldu ",$num1,$action,$num2," je ",$vys;
                       }
      if($action=='-'){

        echo "Vysledek prikaldu ",$num1,$action,$num2," je ",$vys;
                       }
      if($action=='*'){

        echo "Vysledek prikaldu ",$num1,$action,$num2," je ",$vys;
                       }
      if($action=='/'){

        echo "Vysledek prikaldu ",$num1,$action,$num2," je ",$vys;
                       }
    $string="$num1$action$num2=$vys";

    array_push($_SESSION['vysledky'],$string);  

    $con=count($_SESSION['vysledky']);

      if($con>$memory){
        $rozdil=$con-$memory;
          for($i=0; $i<$rozdil; $i++)
             array_shift($_SESSION['vysledky']);
                       }

      echo "<br>Ulozene vypocty:<br> ";
      foreach ($_SESSION['vysledky'] as $value) {
          echo "$value <br>  ";
          } 


?>
```

Comment: Your code has lots of validation to be looked after beside that you can set a var in session like $_SESSION["var"] = "value";

Comment: I know I can set var like that, but I need to store more data (more specified by memory). I dont really need to set 1 static variable.

Comment: do you get any error or anything at all?

Comment: Nothing like error. Basically since it stopped working I didnt even change the code. Except the print_r on start to check storing... I tried to delete cookies, but didnt help. Its so weird so it was working only on my PC on just first browser and then stoped working after reopening...

Comment: There is no problem even with starting session, because if(session_start()=="true")echo "true"; else echo "false"; Returned True. I am really on the end of my ideas...